# WHERE in SQLAlchemy doesn't return the correct value

Tags: python, sql, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a very simple SQL query with WHERE statement.  The correct result is as below.

```
SELECT title, release_year, gross
FROM films
WHERE (release_year >= 1990 AND release_year < 2000)
AND (language = 'French' OR language = 'Spanish')
AND gross > 2000000

title               release_year    gross
El Mariachi          1992           2040920
The Red Violin       1998           9473382
```

However, when I ran

```
pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT title, release_year, gross
                     FROM films
                     WHERE (release_year >= '1990' AND release_year < '2000')
                     AND (language = 'French' OR language = 'Spanish')
                     AND gross > '2000000';''', engine)
```

The result was incorrect

```
    title                            release_year     gross
0   El Mariachi                      1992           2040920
1   Les visiteurs                    1993            700000
2   The Chambermaid on the Titanic   1997            244465
3   The Swindle                      1997            231417
4   La otra conquista                1998            886410
5   The Red Violin                   1998           9473382
```

The `''` around the number seems to matter in `pd.read_sql_query()`. It seems fine when comparing small values (like years) or exact value using `=`.

Does anyone have some suggestion as to solve this?  I want the pd.read_sql_query to return correct data.

Thanks a lot!

@Barmar

In `pd.read_sql_query()`, it is imperative to have single quotation mark around the number.  This is what happen when I ran `pd.read_sql_query` like this

`pd.read_sql_query('''SELECT title, release_year FROM films WHERE release_year >= 1990 ''',  engine)`

The results include wrong years if you don;t have single quotation mark around years

```
title   release_year
0   Intolerance: Love's Struggle Throughout the Ages    1916
1   Over the Hill to the Poorhouse  1920
2   The Big Parade  1925
3   Metropolis  1927
```

Comment: Don't put numbers in quotes.

Comment: Why are you doing that in SQLAlchemy when you don't do it in the reqular SQL?

Comment: The number in pd.read_sql_query must be in quotes.  Otherwise, it will not work at all.

Comment: That makes no sense. The reason for the wrong result is that it's performing a string comparison instead of numeric comparison.

Comment: How are `release_year` and `gross` stored in your database? What data type are they? My guess is that `release_year` is char and `gross` is numeric.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard release_year is integer and gross is bigint.